# Metropolis-Hastings undersampling near kink in distribution function

Tags: metropolis-hastings

I'm trying to use Metropolis-Hastings to sample from a distribution that's very close to

$$\exp(-|x|/\ell)$$

and I'm finding that the method is undersampling near the origin, where there's a kink in the distribution function. I've attached an example figure. Is there a smoothness requirement to Metropolis-Hastings that isn't discussed that often? If so, is there a good workaround for this or alternative algorithm?

[image]

Edit: Here is a minimal working example, along with the output.

```py
def exp_func(x, ell):

    return np.exp(-np.abs(x)/ell)

ell = 2.

sigma = 1.

n_samples = 5000
sequence = np.zeros(n_samples)

theta_t = np.random.random()
idx = 0

while idx < n_samples:
    theta_star = np.random.normal(loc=theta_t, scale=sigma)
    alpha = min(exp_func(theta_star, ell)/exp_func(theta_t, ell), 1.)
    u = np.random.random()
    if u < alpha:
        theta_t = theta_star
        sequence[idx] = theta_star
        idx += 1
```

and what it produces:

[image]

Comment: Done. I hadn't seen anything, so I figured it might be a coding error, but as you note the fit is so good it's hard to imagine where that would be.

Comment: Since the code stops there, do you repeat `theta_t` when `u > alpha` as I do in my R code (last line)?

Comment: Yes, the only time `theta_t` changes is if `u < alpha`. It's worth noting that I tested this with an `exp(-x**4/sigma**4)` type distribution and I don't get this undersampling near the origin.

Comment: Yes, that's what happens. If `u < alpha` then I change `theta_t`, otherwise it stays the same, i.e. when `u > alpha`.

Comment: I fear we have a communication problem, please check my addendum in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

> Differentiability or even continuity is not a requirement for
>   Metropolis to apply (and converge) and the fit is quite good except
>   for the very centre, so I rather foresee a coding error.

Here is an illustration of plain Metropolis working out very well on an  example from [our book](http://amzn.to/2lQDmJR) for the target function$$f(x) \propto \exp(-x^2/2) (\sin(6x)^2+3\cos(x)^2\sin(4x)^2+1)$$which gets easily simulated by accept-reject (Section 2.3.1).

```
x=c()
for(t in 1:1e4){
  y=rnorm(1)#standard Normal proposal
  x=c(x,ifelse(runif(1)<f(y)*dnorm(z)/f(z)/dnorm(y),z<-y,z))}
```

with indeed a very good fit:

[image]

If one forgets to duplicate the current value under a rejection, i.e., to set $X_{t+1}=X_t$, as in

```
 for(t in 1:1e4){y=rnorm(1)
   if(runif(1)<f(y)*dnorm(z)/f(z)/dnorm(y))x=c(x,z<-y)}
```

the fit is lost:

[image]

For the Laplace distribution, here is a comparison between replicating and not-replicating:

[image]

Comment: That's interesting, and yes, I saw my implementation work for other examples with smooth peaks. But your example doesn't have a discontinuity in the derivative, and mine does. Does that matter? Put in a more pathological way, what if my distribution was a step function? Is there a known problem with sampling near a discontinuity in the distribution?